# Unable to map the Number(20) oracle datatype to parquet supported data type

Tags: hive, sqoop

Trying to load the data into hive table which is in parquet format from sqoop. Unable to map oracle data type `number(20)` to `parquet` supported data type.  I am getting an unsupported data type issue. Note: if I cast the `number(20)` to `string` and load the data to hive parquet table, it is loading properly.

SQL Query:  `select seq_no from tbl where $CONDITIONS`

Hive table:

```
create external table if not exists tblname (seq_no double) 
stored as parquet Location '/wkf';
```

Issue: unsupported data type: Double

Comment: Have tried bigint, int , double, binary double nothing worked out.

Comment: Hi, so your sqoop code creates correctly the file but when tried to create the table over that file, it goes in error?

Comment: Hi, @F.Lazarescu the sqoop itself getting failed with the following error "org.kitesdk.data.DatasetOperation: Failed to append {"SYS_REFRESH_SEQ":1000} to ParquetAppender